# How to Monitor a Thread of one instance from a different instance of the same Service in MicroService Architecture

Tags: multithreading, microservices

I have a **Service A** with multiple instances running. In this service we have a Thread pools which runs some async jobs.

Now from some other service **Service B** we initiate a Job on **Service A** by doing a Rest call. Rest call can be received by any one of the instance of **Service A**, so whichever instance receives it on that instance a Thread creates the Job and executes the Job.

Now If I want to stop this job on **Service A** via a Rest Call from **Service B**, but this request can go to any one of the instance of **Service A**.

If the stop request can go to the same instance of **Service A** where the job was initiated, My Stop action will work by killing the Thread which is running the Job but the problem is when this request goes to a different instance of **Service A**.

How can I handle such scenarios in a MicroService Architecture?

Comment: what is your initial analysis and found so far?

Comment: Managing threads in thread pools isn't a microservices architecture concern. This is just implementation details a service shouldn't expose or share with other services. A business fuction or functions is only thing a service should expose via its API.

Comment: @Sohan - We are planning to add one Daemon thread which reads from a shared location to see if any stop request has come than the instance which is running the job will go ahead and stop the job. I just wanted to know if there are any other ways to achieve it.